# i'm trying to make a AI chat bot app like but i keep getting the same error that displays on the device

Tags: dependencies, okhttp

I keep trying to run my code on Android Studios and everything runs fine but when I put in an input text. it shows me that it can't be returned because of okhttp3.internal.http.RealResponseBody@a373b2e

```
package com.varsitycollege.mychatgpt;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    TextView welcomeTextView;
    EditText messageEditText;
    ImageButton sendButton;
    List<Message> messageList;
    MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.get("application/json");
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        messageList = new ArrayList<>();


        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        welcomeTextView = findViewById(R.id.welcome_text);
        messageEditText = findViewById(R.id.message_edit_text);
        sendButton = findViewById(R.id.send_btn);

        //setup recycler view
        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(messageList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        llm.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener((v) ->{
            String question = messageEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            addToChat(question,Message.SENT_BY_ME);
            messageEditText.setText("");
            callAPI(question);
            welcomeTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        });
    }

    void addToChat(String message, String sentBy){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                messageList.add(new Message(message,sentBy));
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messageAdapter.getItemCount());
            }
        });
    }

    void addResponse(String response){
        addToChat(response,Message.SENT_BY_BOT);
    }

    void callAPI(String question){


        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonBody.put("model","gpt-3.5-turbo-0613");
            jsonBody.put("prompt",question);
            jsonBody.put("total_tokens",4000);
            jsonBody.put("temperature",0 );
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jsonBody.toString(),JSON);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.openai.com/v1/audio/transcriptions")
                .header("Authorization","Bearer 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")
                .post(body)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                addResponse("Failed to load a response due to"+e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    try {
                        jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("choices");
                        String result = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0).getString(Integer.parseInt("text"));
                        addResponse(result.trim());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                }else{
                    addResponse("Failed to load response due to "+response.body().toString());
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

I tried to fix the dependency but it is apparently the latest version. I want it to respond when i input text